# LINQ reflection with Host Level Trust

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, trust

I'm having difficulty with my project and deploying it on my web hosting provider.
I'm on a shared hosting environment with "Host Level" trust.

I have used LINQ in my project but now they've just told me that Reflection is disabled on their shared services. I believe that reflection is required to be able to use variables within the queries.

When I run the project in the host level trust environment, I get an Exception:

```
MethodAccessException:
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox`1..ctor(System.__Canon)
```

Does anyone have any experience in this area?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

It's failing on this code:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) {

   using (var dc = new mcDataContext()) {
      var query = (from c in dc.CF_Clients
                   where c.Client_ID == username
                   select new
                   {
                      c.Client_Password
                   }).FirstOrDefault();

  }
}
```

Comment: You do not need reflection permission to be able to use LINQ, you'll have to post the actual code that's causing the problem.

Comment: It appears that you can't use variables in linq statements?

Comment: I've also removed the "var" and replaced it with the proper types, however this doesn't make any difference. It seems to be a problem with the username variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is everything in the query a public member in a public class?

See
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/0dc87db4-c145-456b-a19f-eebc16c09efb/

Another possible solution:

http://www.nullify.net/Article/332.aspx

Comment: Yes, everything is public, and it still does the same thing

Comment: It's clear others have encountered this. I added a link to a blog post that has a different solution. Not sure if you'll have rights to do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
from c in dc.CF_Clients
```

with

```
from Client c in dc.CF_Clients
```

Or whatever your type is (in this case I assumed it is a Client object). If you implicitly cast the objects from the collection, then it shouldn't have to use reflection to access the properties in the query.

Comment: This didn't have any effect. I still get the same message on the same piece of code

Comment: Taking out the username variable in my query, and replacing it with String.Empty, and the code works.